# Application Crash due to empty Value of "Double" data type (android)

Tags: android

I get the following error (in logcat) and my app crashes on my android device when i try to delete the number 0.0(double data type value) from the EditText when launched on my device ..

the following is the error message :

[image: LogCat]

The following is the code :

```
  /*
   * variables prefixed by 'v' are variables of primitive data type
   * variables prefixed by 'et' are edit text
   * variables prefixed by 'cl' are changeListeners of watcher data type 
   * 
   */

   public class MhrSolankiTipCalc extends Activity {

private static final String BILL_BEFORE_TIP = "BILL_BEFORE_TIP";
private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
private static final String FINAL_BILL = "FINAL_AMOUNT";

double vBillAmount, vTipAmount, vFinalBillAmount;

EditText etBillAmount, etTipAmount, etFinalBillAmount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mhr_solanki_tip_calc);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        vBillAmount = 0.0;
        vTipAmount = 0.0;
        vFinalBillAmount = 0.0;
    } else {
        vBillAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_BEFORE_TIP);
        vTipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
        vFinalBillAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(FINAL_BILL);

    }

    etBillAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billBlankEditView);
    etTipAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipBlankEditView);
    etFinalBillAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalEditView);

    etBillAmount.addTextChangedListener(clBillAmount);
    etTipAmount.addTextChangedListener(clTipAmount);

}

private TextWatcher clBillAmount = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        try {
            vBillAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            vBillAmount = 0.0;

        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            vBillAmount=0.0;
        }
        updateBillAndFinalAmount();

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

private TextWatcher clTipAmount = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
            vTipAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            vTipAmount = 0.0;
        }
        updateBillAndFinalAmount();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

public void updateBillAndFinalAmount() {
    double vTipAmount = Double
            .parseDouble(etTipAmount.getText().toString());
    double vBillAmount = Double.parseDouble(etBillAmount.getText()
            .toString());
    double vFinalBillAmount = vBillAmount + (vBillAmount * vTipAmount);
    etFinalBillAmount.setText(String.format("%.02f", vFinalBillAmount));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already parsing `vBillAmount` and `vTipAmount` and catching `NumberFormatException`s in your TextWatchers, you don't need to do it again in the `updateBillAndFinalAmount()` method. This will also fix the `NumberFormatException` you're getting in this method. Change it to:

```
public void updateBillAndFinalAmount()
{
    double vFinalBillAmount = vBillAmount + (vBillAmount * vTipAmount);
    etFinalBillAmount.setText(String.format("%.02f", vFinalBillAmount));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `updateBillAndFinalAmount()` you call `Double.parseDouble` with the values of the EditTexts which are empty strings. You should check them like you do in the text watchers

```
    double vTipAmount; 
    double vBillAmount;
    try {
        vTipAmount = Double.parseDouble(etTipAmount.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        vTipAmount = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        vBillAmount = Double.parseDouble(etBillAmount.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        vBillAmount = 0.0;
    }
```

and instead of copy/paste this whole block you can simply write a function that return a double by your specific rules

```
public static double getDoubleFromString(String s)
{
    double d;
    try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        d = 0.0;
    }
    return d;
}
```

and your code will look like

```
 double vTipAmount = getDoubleFromString(etTipAmount.getText().toString()); 
 double vBillAmount = getDoubleFromString(etBillAmount.getText().toString());
```

Comment: well that was pretty dumb of me to check the values of variables and not of the string entered in EditText views :P ..
Just started into android development so sliped out of my mind .. 
Kudos and thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Before providing the string value you get from the `EditText` to `parseDouble()`, make sure it's not null:

```
vTipAmount = (s.toString().length > 0 && s.toString() != null)
             ? Double.parseDouble(s.toString())
             : 0.0;
```

An alternative is to catch all Exceptions instead of just NumberFormatException (it adds a bit minimal overhead though):

```
    try {
        vBillAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        vBillAmount = 0.0;

    }
```

Comment: Well thanks for you answer... totally forgot about the ifelse shorthand operator .. While this does the job for one thing , i would rather consider making a function as answered by mihail above ..